# Keyboard interrupt not working in x64 based machine on latest linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, interrupt, keyboardinterrupt

Here is the basic kernel module that I have coded:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
// irq number for keyboard is 1
static int irq = 1,  dev = 0xaa, counter = 0;

static irqreturn_t keyboard_handler(int irq, void *dev)
{
        pr_info("Keyboard Counter:%d\n", counter++);
        return IRQ_NONE;
}
/* registering irq */
static int test_interrupt_init(void)
{
        pr_info("%s: In init\n", __func__);
        return request_irq(irq, keyboard_handler, IRQF_SHARED,"my_keyboard_handler", &dev);
}

static void test_interrupt_exit(void)
{
        pr_info("%s: In exit\n", __func__);
        synchronize_irq(irq); /* synchronize interrupt */
        free_irq(irq, &dev);
}

module_init(test_interrupt_init);
module_exit(test_interrupt_exit);
```

This module counts the number of generated keyboard interrupts and prints it to the kernel printk circular buffer.

The problem is that the keyboard_handler is never getting executed.

Some debugging information that I want to share:
Before loading this module, the output of `sudo cat /proc/interrupts | less` is

```
            CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       CPU4       CPU5       CPU6       CPU7       CPU8       CPU9       CPU10      CPU11      CPU12      CPU13      CPU14      CPU15      
   1:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0         93  IR-IO-APIC    1-edge      i8042
```

After loading the module, the output of the same command is

```
            CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       CPU4       CPU5       CPU6       CPU7       CPU8       CPU9       CPU10      CPU11      CPU12      CPU13      CPU14      CPU15      
   1:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0         93  IR-IO-APIC    1-edge      i8042, my_keyboard_handler
```

This suggests that my request_irq function call has registered my keyboard_handler successfully.

The dmesg output is:

```
[48485.839232] test_interrupt_init: In init
[48504.831010] test_interrupt_exit: In exit
```

The steps I have followed to get this dmesg output:

```
$ sudo insmod hello.ko
$ sdsds
sdsds: command not found
$ sudo rmmod hello
```

Details of the machine where I was trying to execute this code:

```
$ uname -r
5.18.0-4mx-amd64
```

I am using the MX-Linux distro

I was expecting the keyboard_handler function to get executed that will increase the counter variable to each keyboard interrupt and print its value in the kernel print buffer.

--Edited--

Note: The interrupt count value in my /proc/interrupts for IRQ1 is also not incrementing though I am pressing the keyboard buttons. Thanks to @Ian Abbott for pointing it out.

Comment: Have you checked whether the counts for IRQ1 in /proc/interrupts increase after generating keyboard interrupts with your module loaded?

Comment: They are not increasing for IRQ1 in /proc/interrupts

Comment: Stupid question, but is your keyboard plugged into the PS/2 keyboard port?

Comment: this is dell alienware, builtin keyboard. so I have no idea how this builtin laptop keyboard is connected to the motherboard.

Comment: The /proc/bus/input/devices file may provide some clues.

Comment: I could see three keyboard devices:

N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input0
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd leds event0 

N: Name="DELL Technologies Keyboard"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-10/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-10/1-10:1.0/0003:0D62:0A1C.0005/input/input17
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd leds event13

N: Name="ACPI Virtual Keyboard Device"
P: Phys=
S: Sysfs=/devices/virtual/input/input36
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event29 rfkill

Comment: If you install the `evtest` package and run `sudo evtest`, it will list the input event devices and prompt to select one. Select one of the keyboard devices (usually number 0) to monitor events on that device. If it shows events being generated when you press and release keys then you know which device is your keyboard.

Comment: I got the keyboard device which generates intterupt. The details are: 
N: Name="DELL Technologies Keyboard"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-10/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-10/1-10:1.0/0003:0D62:0A1C.0005/input/input16
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd leds event13
. It is event13. How to map it to interrupt number and I/O port address from where I will get the data?

Comment: You will not be able to hook up an interrupt handler to collect data from a USB keyboard easily. I suggest implementing an input handler and registering it with the input subsystem.

Answer (score 0):

same question. Wonder if it has been solved...